# How can I convert a list to string

Tags: android, list, kotlin

```
data class Movie( 
    @SerializedName("movie_name")
    val movieName : String
    @SerializedName("genres")
    val movieGenre : List<String>){}
```

How can I convert a list to string created every object in this data class

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to do? Like what list should be converted to string and how?

Comment: movieGenre comes from the internet as a list, I need to translate it String

Comment: To a single `String`? How should it be separated? Not at all? You would get genres like `"horrorsplatterromancecomedy"`... Maybe comma separated? Please add the requirements to your question.

Comment: movieGenre comes [romantic, comedy,....] i need val movieGenre = Romantic Comedy ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use additional property in `Movie` class to convert list to string, e.g. `val genre`:

```
data class Movie(
        @SerializedName("movie_name")
        val movieName: String,
        @SerializedName("genres")
        val movieGenre: List<String>
) {
    val genre: String
        get() = buildString { // builds new string using append() method on each item of movieGenre
            movieGenre.forEach { append(it) }
        }

}
```

Here is how to access it:

```
val movie: Movie = getMoviewFromInternet()
val movieGenre: String = movie.genre
```

Answer (score 2):

That's achievable in Kotlin via `joinToString(separator: String)`, like this:

```
data class Movie( 
    @SerializedName("movie_name")
    val movieName : String,
    @SerializedName("genres")
    val movieGenre : List<String>
) {
    val genre: String
        // concatenate the items using the separator provided
        get() = movieGenre.joinToString(" ")
}
```

You would use it in a `main` as follows

```
fun main() {
    val genreList: List<String> = listOf(
        "Horror", "Splatter", "Romance", "Comedy", "Mystery", "Adult"
    )
    val movieName = "A.R. Bitrary"

    val movie = Movie(movieName, genreList)

    println(movie.genre)
}
```

which then outputs

```
Horror Splatter Romance Comedy Mystery Adult
```